# Can a python3 subprocess feed directly into another?

Tags: python3

Linux Mint 18.3, python 3.5.2. Is something similar to this program possible?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

wlist = subprocess.run(['wc', '-w'],
    stdin=subprocess.run(['ls'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout
print(wlist)
```

This can be done with separate subprocess statements, writing to and reading from disk. If it can be done in one statement, it should use less CPU, memory, and disk I/O.

Comment: If you are concerned about efficiency and resources, you would probably not want to call shell utilities to do things that Python library functions could probably do for you.

Comment: The program snippet is just an example. The actual programs involved are user written.

Comment: IMHO, it's possible if you don't mind creating a new class or function. A function or class can serve as single statement, but it needs to be created first. I don't think there's anything build into Python like that.